# For 400 bad request in cxfrs:rsclient in camel, the exchange is null. For 200 http status, the exchange object is set

Tags: apache-camel, httpresponse, jbossfuse, bad-request, cxfrs

Below is the code snippet to consume an api endpoint. For 200 http response, the exchange object contains the payload received. But for 400 response, the payload received is not set in exchange object. Is anything missing in the code below?

```
Exchange exchange = serviceProducer.send(endPoint, new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
                Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
                inMessage.setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_USING_HTTP_API, Boolean.TRUE);
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "clientId=" + ClientId);
                inMessage.setBody(request);
                inMessage.setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_RESPONSE_CLASS, SearchResponse.class);
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            }
        });
SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse) exchange.getOut().getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getOut()` creates a blank output message. You need to use `getIn()` or `getMessage()`.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse) exchange.getIn().getBody();
```

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html#UsinggetInorgetOutmethodsonExchange-UsinggetInorgetOutmethodsonExchange

Comment: Thanks! But ..exchange.getIn().getBody() is giving the request body being sent, rather than giving the response body.
For 200 response exchange.getOut().getBody() is having the reponse body, but not for 400

Comment: in that case, could you log all properties and headers for the out exchange and check what is logged for a 400 response?